# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. ...coe/prognostic-data-repository/\#battery}}

Tags: bibtex, errors, citing, url, bbl

My Master's thesis has a problem with citing a certain entry. It gives me the following error: "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. ...coe/prognostic-data-repository/#battery}}"

My .tex-file (minimalized) looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[ 12pt,               % Font size
twoside,            % Comment if you want to print on one side
openright,
headsepline,        % Adds a line under the page header
headings=small,     % Defines sizing of the headers
numbers=noenddot,   % No point at the right side of the section number
%draft=false,
BCOR=15mm,          % Absolute value of the binding correction.
DIV=10,             % larger value --> larger use of the page
%captions=tableheading,
paper=a4,           % only change if you want  another paper size
abstracton,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf
%We use PDFLaTeX
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\pdfimageresolution=100
\pdfminorversion=7
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\usepackage[pdftex,
urlcolor=blue,
linktoc=all,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
pdfview=FitH,
pdfstartview=FitH,
plainpages=false]{hyperref} % Allows cross references and hyperlinks
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Your Name},
    pdftitle={Name of your thesis},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfkeywords={Keywords},
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref},
    pdfcreator={pdflatex}}
\usepackage[figure,figure*]{hypcap}
\else
%DVI oder PS Ausgabe
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\fi
\usepackage{pdfpages}   

\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\newcommand{\Literaturename}{Literature}

\begin{document}
    \citet{Saha.data}

    \protect\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{Literature}
\end{document}
```

And my .bib-file includes the Saha.data-entry as follows:

```
@misc{Saha.data,
 author = {Saha, B. and Goebel, K.},
 year = {2007},
 title = {{Battery Data Set}},
 url = {\url{https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/dash/groups/pcoe/prognostic-data-repository/#battery}},
 publisher = {{NASA AMES Prognostics Data Repository}},
 institution = {{NASA Ames Research Center, Moffett Field, CA}}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `url` field, you do not have to include `\url` in the  Bibtex `url` filed. The `plainnat` style will insert it for you.

If you do include `\url` then, in the `bbl` file you will have

```
\newblock URL
  \url{\url{https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/dash/groups/pcoe/prognostic-data-repository/#battery}}.
```

and this causes the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Guido!
This is the solution for my problem. However it wasn't working as I tried this before posting my question. Additionally I had to delete my `bbl`-file before compiling again.

Also since I'm using Citavi as literature management tool when exporting from there I need to make sure that _use URL-package_ remains unchecked!